# symfony4 handleRequest not working correctly with fileType in form

Tags: forms, symfony4, assert, file-type

Im trying to validate my form, it has a fileType field in it.
I use asserts to validate the form. The validation works correctly for all field except the fileType field.
It is only allowed to upload jpg jpeg and png files, but if I try to upload for example a PDF file it says my form is valid.

This is the code of the field holding the filename in the db

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="imgHomepage", type="string")
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "1024k",
 *     mimeTypes = {"image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Images must be  jpg,  jpeg or  png"
 * )
 */
private $imgHomepage = '';
```

This is the code of my fileType being added in the formtype of my entity

```
->add('imgHomepage', FileType::class, [
            'mapped' => false,
            'data_class' => null,
            'required' => false,
            'error_bubbling' => true
 ])
```

This is the code from my controller

```
$influencer = self::getInfluencerById($influencerId);
$influencerShowForm = self::CreateInfluencerForm($influencer);
$influencerShowForm->handleRequest($request);
if ($influencerShowForm->isSubmitted() && $influencerShowForm->isValid()) {
  // handle form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because the field is not mapped, so it does not validate it against the Entity where your Assert annotation is located. Also, that column is a string and your Assert says it must be a file, you should use a different property for the file itself that does not have a column defined (unmapped).

Try setting the `constraints` option when you add the `FileType` field in the FormType:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

...

->add('imgHomepage', FileType::class, [
            'mapped' => false,
            'data_class' => null,
            'required' => false,
            'error_bubbling' => true,
            'constraints' => new Assert\File([
              'maxSize' => '1024k',
              'mimeTypes' => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"],
              'mimeTypesMessage' => "Images must be  jpg,  jpeg or  png",
            ])
 ])
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html#form-validation

Comment: Arleigh Hix, thx for the answer, but this doesn't seem to work for me. I'm not gonna bother spending time on this problem for a while. I might take a look at it in a couple weeks with a frehs head :p